# Regex match a string and allow specific character to appear randomly

Tags: regex

I want to extract a portion of a string, allowing for the dash character to appear randomly throughout. In my match, I want the dash character occurrences to be included.

Let's say I have a scenario like so:

```
haystack = "arandomse-que-nce"
needle   = "sequence"
```

and I want to come out on the other end with a string like `se-que-nce` this this case, what would the regex pattern look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s-*e-*q-*u-*e-*n-*c-*e-*
```

The assumes that multiple hyphens in a row are okay.

EDIT: Doorknob's split/join solution is good, but be aware that it only works for character that aren't special characters (*, +, etc.)

I don't know what the specifications are, but if there are special characters, make sure to escape them:

```
new RegExp(needle.split('').map(function(c) { return '\\' + c; }).join('-*'))
```

Comment: Went with this solution, utilizing @Doorknob's split/join method to insert the `-*` elements to the string.

Comment: @YWCAHello, I would have suggested split/join if I had known what programming language to use. See updated answer.

Comment: `/` does NOT escape... you just completely broke the code... try it

Comment: Still broken. It will turn `s` into `\s`, which will break it.

Comment: The question concerns the regular expression needed to get the job done. The programmatic generation of it, given a particular string, while tangentially of interest, is not part of the question. That being said, it would be great if the example worked for future readership.

Answer (score 3):

I would split the string and then join by `-*`; for example, in JavaScript:

```
var needle   = "sequence"
var regex    = new RegExp(needle.split('').join('-*'))
var result   = "arandomse-que-nce".match(regex) // ["se-que-nce"]
var result2  = "a-bad-sequ_ence".match(regex)   // null
```

You could also use a regex to insert `-*` between each character:

```
var regex    = new RegExp(needle.replace(/(?!$|^)/g, '-*'))
```

Both the `split`/`join` method and the `replace` method return `'s-*e-*q-*u-*e-*n-*c-*e'` for the regex.

If you have characters like `*` in your string, that have meanings in regular expressions, you may want to escape them, like so:

```
var regex    = new RegExp(needle.replace(/(?!$|^)/g, '-*')
                                .replace(/([-\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}])/g, '\\$1'))
```

Then, if `needle` was `1+1`, for example, it would give you `1-*\+-*1` for the regex.

Comment: Instead of splitting and joining, you could just use a regex (how meta!): `var regex = needle.replace(/[^-]/g,'$&-*')`

Comment: @EthanBrown How meta indeed! :P I edited my answer with a different one; yours added an extra `-*` at the end

Comment: Almost correct, but this doesn't account for strings where more than one dash occurs in sequence.

Comment: @YWCAHello Oh, then simply use `-*` instead. In your question, you only had one dash, so I assumed you only wanted to validate one. Edited.

Comment: Nice answer!  And good catch on the extra `*` at the end, and remembering to mention escaping metacharacters.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use:

```
s-?e-?q-?u-?e-?n-?c-?e
```